# Selenium - saving all mime-types to disk

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm attempting to use Python Selenium to download a set of HWP ("Haansoft Word Processor") files. No matter what I set in the Firefox browser profile configuration, however, the download manager opens. I've tested the following code for other mime-types (pdf, doc), and it seems to work just fine (i.e., without opening the download manager).

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",downloaddir)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
        "application/x-hwp,application/hwp,application/haansofthwp")
```

Is there some way to set `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` to all mime-types?

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the download dialog, you have to be sure about the exact MIME type and give it to the profile (as you did, but maybe not with the right mime type). you will have to write them all down to the preferences, at least to my knowledge.

get an overview of [MIME types here:](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMimeTypesAndApplications.html)

also helpful could be the line

```
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
```

, just to be sure ;)

if you dont know the MIME type and yu are on windows, you can try [the free software fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) to find out the MIME type. its an analyze tool for http traffic. an nice tutorial on fiddler usage [can be found here](http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/fiddler-in-action/part-1)